# JSON invalid character found

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a MySQL query in order to get some records from a DB.
Then, inside a loop I have a PHP array and in the end I have `json_encode()` PHP function. The values I am  getting from the DB, has some HTML tags, thus, the `json_encode()` does not work.

Please take a look at the sample code:

```
$pr_arr['products'][] = array(
                "id"                => $results_products->id,
                "business_id"       => $results_products->business_id,
                "pid"               => $results_products->pid,
                "category"          => $results_products->category,
                "style_mapping"     => $results_products->style_mapping,
                "name"              => $product_name,
                "price"             => $price,
                "offer_price"       => $offer_price,
                "product_link"      => $product_link,
                "image_url"         => $product_image,
                "size"              => $results_products->size,
                "manufacturer"      => $product_manufacturer,
                "description"       => $product_description,
                "color"             => $results_products->color,
                "sku"               =>  $results_products->sku,
                "mpn"               => $results_products->mpn,
                "instock"           => $results_products->instock,
                "availability"      => $results_products->availability,
                "date_added"        => $results_products->date_added
            );
```

The `$product_description` is the one that has the issue. If I comment this line of code, the JSON in valid and correct!

The validation I am seeing from the https://jsonlint.com/ (and if I view it in browser is this):

```
"manufacturer":"combos","description":"
\\\\n\tv-\u03bb\u03b1\u03b9\u03bc\u03cc\u03ba\u03bf\u03c8\u03b7<\/li>
\\\\n\t\u03c0\u03b1\u03c4\u03b9\u03bb\u03ad\u03c4\u03b1 \u03bc\u03b5 \u03ba\u03bf\u03c5\u03bc\u03c0\u03b9\u03ac<\/li>
\\\\n\t\u03bc\u03b1\u03bd\u03c3\u03ad\u03c4\u03b5\u03c2 \u03ba\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c3\u03c4\u03c1\u03af\u03c6\u03c9\u03bc\u03b1 \u03c3\u03b5 rib \u03c0\u03bb\u03ad\u03be\u03b7<\/li>
regular fit<\/li>
```

I read, that when you are opening the double quotes I need to have everything in the same row. But nothing, I have already tried worked. I tried to replace the new lines with empty spaces, escape special characters (\n, \r, \t, and so on)

Could someone tell me how to solve this issue, so I could help the description (with HTML tags), inside my JSON?

thanks in advance!

Comment: what is Unicode type? I think this issue related with unicode...or try to set json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for this fast reply.
Actually, this is a PHP file, and it is working like script, creating dynamically the json output..
Thus, I do not have unicode or something.. Could you be more specific?

I have the connection of the DB and inside this file I have these two lines:
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Welcome mate, To be more specific, the result in your question related for Unicode issue , so that you can try to UNESCAPED Unicode like first line...now the php script is convert db data or you got it from file its no defferant...but you can make sure that file.php is also utf-8 Unicode ...not ascii code ...

Comment: see this json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); or look at full option here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I am using PHPStorm... if that helps.. how could I check the file.php if it is utf-8 Unicode? I am trying all these you are saying (this is my code at the end, with the array variable): echo json_encode($pr_arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
but no luck..What I am doing wrong?

Comment: mmm, If you are using PHPStorm, its use utf8 by default, you can check footer bar and you will see a file Unicode,  I use this code "json_encode($resArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)" in our real project and I check it again...its work fine...mmm for testing rezone if you set a static array in $product_description with English char only and execute code...is return a truth value?

Comment: correct PHPStorm says utf-8 in the footer.. the $product_description has Greek words and HTML tags..I did not check with english chars if I have the same result to be onest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add flags in your `json_encode` command
`json_encode($yourArrayVar, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);`
or
`json_encode($yourArrayVar, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_TAG);`
Also try to mix it with Anis Hikmat Abu-hmiad flag

Comment: Actually this one Alex solved my problem
json_encode($yourArrayVar, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
the first suggestion.. thanks a lot .. and many thanks to you Anis, too!